# Unable to open iterator for alias in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I was doing some experiments in pig(hadoop mode).
I loaded the sample data into HDFS ,

```
a   A   1
b   B   2
c   C   3
a   AA  11
a   AAA 111
b   BB  22
```

hdfs://#######/data/one
Then I logged into grunt shell, I fired the `ls`. I can able to see the file in the hdfs.

I loaded the data like this:
data = load 'data/one' using PigStorage();

Then I fired the `dump data` but I'm getting the error like this

```
Failed Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
job_201111102206_22874  data    MAP_ONLY        Message: Job failed! Error - Job initialization failed:
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSError: java.io.IOException: No space left on device

.
.
.
2011-12-17 23:48:32,687 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Failed!
2011-12-17 23:48:32,689 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias <b>data</b>
```

This same process I had executed many times, it worked for me but not now and this is also working well in local mode.

And last thing , I had the checked the data, there is no unnecessary space.

Any suggestion?

Comment: For people who found this post when looking for [ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495085/error-1066-unable-to-open-iterator-for-alias-in-pig-generic-solution) here is a [generic solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34495086/983722).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the slave node that is processing your query has run out of disk space.